# why python 3 or 2 can't give output to this code with Input : 0 1 10 [in a single line]

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a=input()
d=a.strip(' ')
a=int(d[0])
b=int(d[2])
c=int(d[4])
for i in range(0,c-2):
    p = b**2 + a
    a=b
    b=p
print (p)

#This code is working fine, if the input is: 0 1 9 but not when the input is: 0 1 10
```

Comment: You can accept Ewan's answer by clicking on the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

Change `d=a.strip()` to `d=[int(x) for x in a.strip().split(' ')]`

Then use:

```
a, b, c = d
```

This works in the following way:

- `a.strip().split(' ')` -> Convert the string into a `list`, separating every  (whitespace)
- `int(x)` convert to an `int` for each element in that list `for x`
- create a new list and assign to `d`.
- All of this is called a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)
- Now we have a list like this `d = [0, 1, 10]`
- assign each variable to an element in the list `a, b, c = d`

**Why was it breaking?**

You'll get an error `p was not defined` because it will never enter your `for` loop (where `p` is defined).

In your code, the raw input is a `string` that you're selecting elements of.

`input = "0 1 9"` is being treated as `0`, , `1`, , `9`

`input = "0 1 10"` is being treated as `0`, , `1`, , `1`, `0` where `c=1`.

So your code is trying to do `range(0,-1)` and will never enter the `for` loop.

Comment: Working fine.. Thank you :)

Comment: @user3664956 - if I've helped you please upvote/accept my answer. Please pay attention to the explanations myself and EthanFurman gave to understand why it was failing. Thanks

Comment: Nice solution to the problem.   You might want to break the steps down, though -- a list-comp is more advanced.

Comment: @EthanFurman Good point, well made. Updated my answer to reflect this

Answer (score 3):

When the input is `0 1 10` your code interprets that as `0`, `1`, `1`.  Specifically, the line

```
c = int(d[4])
```

takes the fourth character, not the fourth and fifth. Because `c` ends up being `1` and not `10`, your range is never entered, and `p` is never defined.

Comment: but the code is running fine, if I input 0 1 5
when I input 0 1 10. "Error: p was not defined" is displayed